# How do I change the looks of the structure guide lines in VS2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

The new structure guide lines in VS2017 are extremely confusing, as they are positioned in the middle of a character, instead of to the left. The biggest problem is that I don't know when my cursor is ALL the way to the left, as it seems to be when it is standing on the grid line, but it may off by one.

How can I change them to look more like Visual Code? I know how to enable and disable them but can't find any way to alter their looks.

No guide lines in VS2017: This does not help me much.
[image: Without structure guide lines]

With guide lines in VS2017: This is awful, it looks like there is just 1 space between two guide lines, when in fact there are two!
[image: With structure guide lines]

Guide lines in Visual Code: Very helpful.
[image: Structure guide lines in VSC]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found [this plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteveDowerMSFT.IndentGuides), which fixes the main off-by-one problem and works for VS2017. See below for a screenshot of the indent guides added by the plugin.

[image: Better indent guides]

The plugin is customizable, such that you can get a solid line if preferred.